# Android Emulator is huge

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

I am trying to start a emulator to develop a mobile app, due to the huge size of the emulator the icons do not response on clicks.

Attached is the emulator started from AVD. I have tried to edit the device settings, disable the frame around the screen. Nothing seems to work.

Emulator Specs: Pixel 3a API 30, Resolution-1080x2220

[image: Attached is the emulator started from AVD. I have tried to edit the device settings, disable the frame Emulator Specs: Pixel 3a API 30, Resolution-1080x2220]

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue, in my case restarting the emulator did work.

Or create your own custom emulator

Comment: No, restarting the emulator didn't do it. I shall look into creating my own emulator and see if that helps

Comment: Yeah it should.

Answer (score 0):

Go to AVD Manager and try **Cold boot Now** and if that doesn't work then try **Wipe Data**.
[image]
Also, Let us know how the issue got fixed.

Comment: It still is as in the picture, Do you think creating my custom emulator may fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Cold boot your emulator in order to refresh.

[image]

Comment: I did try cold boot, stays the same  after the cold boot